# Error when updating T3 template and T3 plugin: "Invalid extension update"

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, one-click-updates, t3-framework

On a website I have a template installed which also installed the T3 framework.

Each time I get a notification about an update but when installing an error occurs:

> Invalid extension update

All other updates work without any issues. In previous attempts I also tried manually updating. But it did not fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: One click updates never worked for T3.

Comment: You could try the JAEM (JA Extension Manager Component) http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/extensions/ja-extensions-manager. There are known issues, so JAEM is the recommended way to update T3 - see here http://www.joomlart.com/documentation/wiki-ja-extension-manager/how-to#Known_issues

Comment: I would also let the developer know just incase it's a bug within those 2 specific extensions.

Comment: I have the problems some times also. What i do is that i download and update t3 framework and template manually. That usally does the trick.

Comment: @ValentinDespa This question should be reopened. Answers to this question could be helpful for people with the same problem, for example me.

Comment: @ChristopherWallace - Reopened.

Comment: I think this is T3 Framework bug so you should report it on official website http://www.t3-framework.org/

Comment: Are you using the Joomlart Extension Manager? If so, does the one click upgrades work for any of the other extensions? I have been using this framework extensively he past few months and ran into a few issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is very odd indeed. I think the problem comes from the creator. Then, there is nothing else we can do from downstream.

To solve it, just manually download and update it from [T3 for Joomla!](http://www.t3-framework.org/downloads.html). At the end of the downloads list, you can find **T3 Framework plugin**.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the changelog on [Github](https://github.com/t3framework/t3/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and cannot find any references to bug fixes for the extension manager, therefore I don't think it's a big with the extension manager itself.

I believe at the time, it was due to an issue with their update XML file. Either an incorrect download URL or target platform.

What I'd suggest doing is downloading version 2.4.8(template) from Github:

https://github.com/t3framework/t3/releases/tag/v2.4.8

Purge the Joomla cache, and then trying to find an update for T3 again. It should show you one for v2.4.9(template).